# Не корректно работает rewriteRule в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Столкнулся с такой бедой - не корректно обрабатывается rewriterule в htaccess при кажущейся простоте в обработке. не понимаю в какую сторону рыть, настройки сервера?

имею htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.net/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.php$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php\?la\=$1&url\=$2&country\=$3&region\=$4&city\=$5&dop\=$6 [QSA,L] #/ru/forecast/Russia/Murmansk/Apatity/10days - <b>ЗДЕСЬ ПРОБЛЕМА!!!</b>
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$      index.php\?la\=$1&url\=$2&country\=$3&region\=$4&city\=$5 [QSA,L] #/ru/forecast/Russia/Murmansk/Apatity
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$           index.php\?la\=$1&url\=$2&country\=$3&region\=$4 [QSA,L] #/ru/forecast/Russia/Murmansk
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$                index.php\?la\=$1&url\=$2&country\=$3 [QSA,L] #/ru/forecast/Russia/
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$                     index.php\?la\=$1&url\=$2 [QSA,L] #/ru/forecast/
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)/?$                      index.php\?la\=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  !images
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  !tr

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

при запросе

domain.net/ru/forecast/Russia/Moscow_oblast/Trostniki/ - выдает все как надо
т.е. la="ru", url="forecast", country="Russia" и т.д.

и при других запросах с меньшим кол-вом параметров тоже работает на ура.

НО при запросе:

domain.net/ru/forecast/Russia/Moscow_oblast/Trostniki/10days/ - параметр la (первый в обработке в htaccess) принимает значение la="ru/forecast" - соответственно, все остальные параметры получаются не корректные

разные вариации перепробовал, но так и не понял, в чем беда?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло это: заменить `.*` на `[^/]+`.